# Looping through Pandas dict within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column who's rows each contain a dict.

I would like to extract those dict's and turn them into dataframes so I can merge them together.

What's the best way to do this?

Something like:

```
for row in dataframe.column:
    dataframe_loop = pd.DataFrame(dataframe['column'].iloc(row), columns=['A','B'])
    dataframe_result = dataframe_result.append(dataframe_loop)
```

Comment: What's the problem with your solution? I suspect you're missing an `iteritems` for the loop to work.

Comment: What are the keys in the dictionaries?  How should they relate to columns in the new dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col': pd.Series([{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

>>>print(df)

      col 
 0  {'a': 1} 
 1  {'b': 2} 
 2  {'c': 3}

res = {}

for row in df.iterrows():
    res.update(row[1]['col'])

>>>print(res) 
{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column contains dicts and you want to make a dataframe out of those dicts, you can just convert the column to a list of dicts and make that into a dataframe directly:

```
pd.DataFrame(dataframe['column'].tolist())
```

The dictionary keys will become columns.  If you want other behavior, you'll need to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your dict in `dataframe.column` looks like. If it looks like the dictionary below, I think you can use `pandas.concat` to concentrate dictionaries together.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dummy dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'column':[{'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]}, \
                                    {'A':[7,8,9], 'B':[10,11,12]}, \
                                    {'A':[13,14,15], 'B':[16,17,18]}]})

#print(dataframe)

res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(row, columns=['A', 'B']) for row in dataframe.column], ignore_index=True)

print(res)
```